# Join two tables and return data and count in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Link [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3038a/2)

I have this tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` (
    `project_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `id_location` varchar (50) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`))DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
    `location_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` varchar (50) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`))DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `project` (`project_id`, `id_location`) VALUES
  ('1', '4'),
 ('2', '4'),
 ('3', '4'),
 ('4', '5'),
 ('5', '5'),
 ('6', '6'),
  ('7', '7');
  
 INSERT INTO `location` (`location_id`, `parent_id`) VALUES
 ('2', '1'),
 ('3', '1'),
 ('4', '2'),
 ('5', '2'),
 ('6', '3'),
  ('7', '3');
```

I use this query to obtain the following result:

```
SELECT project.project_id 
     , project.id_location
     , location.parent_id 
  FROM project
  LEFT 
  JOIN location  
    ON project.id_location = location.id



| project_id | id_location | parent_id   |
| 1          | 4           | 2           |
| 2          | 4           | 2           |
| 3          | 4           | 2           |
| 4          | 5           | 2           |
| 5          | 5           | 2           |
| 6          | 6           | 3           |
| 7          | 7           | 3           |
```

I want to get the list of parent_id  along with count of project_id . I will use after a condition like where parent_id = x

```
|parent_id   | countofproject_id 
| 2          | 5           
| 3          | 2
```

Comment: Provided sqlfiddle link

Comment: Please show us the result that you want, as tabular text.

Comment: What would the desired result look like? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: you can use inner join between two tables and group by parent_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an aggregation:

```
SELECT l.parent_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM project p LEFT JOIN
     location l
     ON p.id_location = l.id
GROUP BY l.parent_id;
```

It is unclear why you are using a `LEFT JOIN` here.  It is a bad practice to aggregate by a column in the *second* table.  So, you might just want an `INNER JOIN`.

If you want all *parent id*s, then reverse the tables:

```
SELECT l.parent_id, COUNT(p.id_location) 
FROM location l LEFT JOIN
     project p 
     ON p.id_location = l.id
GROUP BY l.parent_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works for my initial request. I would also want now to go further and i would like to achive something  like this:<br/>     `"SELECT l.*, (SELECT l.parent_id, COUNT(*) FROM project p INNER JOIN location l ON p.id_location = l.id GROUP BY l.parent_id) AS counted ".
 "FROM location l ".
 "WHERE l.parent_id = 2 AND l.published=1 ".   
 "ORDER BY thecount desc "; `

Comment: @Catalin . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  Ask a new question if you didn't ask exactly the question you intended.  This question is answered.